# syntax error when cast in EXTRACT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just try this and I got a syntax error with tdate (it a DATE type)

```
select *
from treatment
where  EXTRACT(month FROM cast (date as TIMESTAMP) tdate) = EXTRACT(month FROM cast (date as TIMESTAMP) current_date)
```

is anyone can help me out..??
thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need to bother casting either field since you should be able to extract the month directly from both. I would try:

```
select * 
from treatment 
where extract(month from tdate) = extract(month from current_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for instead:

```
select *
from treatment
where EXTRACT(month FROM cast (tdate as TIMESTAMP)) = 
      EXTRACT(month FROM cast (current_date as TIMESTAMP))
```

It should be `cast(field as type)` where you have `cast(date as type)`.